# Restricting login in text mode of standard user

Tags: virtual-console

How can I restrict login of standard user in text mode?I want only root to be able to access this.

Answer (score 0):

many processes utilise pam.d configuration to create process when starting application and services. I don't know if you can accomplish what you want but you can trie:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-restrict-log-in-capabilities-of-users-on-ubuntu

Best regards
Adam B.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.